# How to correctly install Subversion in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, svn

A task has emerged to install latest subversion for a group of mac os x users (latest mac os version). I have tried first to install it manually from subversion.tigris.org, 'opencollabnet binary' (http://downloads.open.collab.net/binaries.html, "Universal Subversion 1.6.3 Binaries for MAC OS X (32 and 64 bit)"). It installed ok via .pkg installer, but after using 'svn' command I was surprised to see an old 1.4.4 version bundled with macos.

It seems, that installing new subversion does not replace an old one. What is a 'correct' way to ensure that 'svn' command always uses newly installed subversion? I can create a symlink or add /opt/bla-bla-bla/subversion to path, but I'm afraid that such crude hacking can break something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to prepend the /opt/subversion version in the shell's path to have the environment prefer the new version.

The software's [README](http://www.open.collab.net/nonav/downloads/community/readme/macosx.html) states:

> **Installation Notes**
>
> <snip>
>
> Once installed, you will
>   need  to prepend /opt/subversion/bin
>   to your PATH environment variable.
>   This can be done a multitude of ways
>   but an easy one is to add the 
>   following to the end of /etc/profile
>   or ~/.profile:
>
> export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

get [macports](http://www.macports.org/), set it up properly, and install svn from there with:

sudo port install subversion

Comment: Is it the only way? Installing from macports is a LONG process. Isn't it a way to use official binaries somehow? I'm sure they are created in order to be used :)

Comment: @Eye of Hell - It takes a while but takes a lot of the management of packages out of the way - if Subversion is the only CLI tool you're going to install then I wouldn't. Most tools don't offer .pkg installers however.

Comment: Yeah and because MacPorts isn't updated too often, I don't like using it.